# How to make custom view observe containing fragment's lifecycle events instead of activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have an activity and several fragments that it replaces inside a frame layout. Each fragment contains a layout inflated from XML with a number of custom views. Inside those views, I want to subscribe to lifecycle events in these views using LifecycleObserver. My view in Kotlin:

```
class MyView(context: Context) : View(context, null, 0): LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        (getContext() as LifecycleOwner).lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun onResume() {
        // code
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun onPause() {
        // code
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }

}
```

The problem is, when one fragment goes away and is replaced by another, the views in the first fragment don't receive an **onPause** event. Nor do they get **onResume** when I return to it from the second fragment. The views receive **onPause** only when the whole **activity** is paused, but they are unaware of lifecycle changes in the **fragments**. I tracked this down to layout inflater, that is used to inflate fragment's xml layout, it passes the activity as **context** parameter to views. This is how layout inflater is instantiated in support library's Fragment class:

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
@NonNull
@RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP})
public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater(@Nullable Bundle savedFragmentState) {
    if (this.mHost == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.");
    } else {
        LayoutInflater result = this.mHost.onGetLayoutInflater();
        this.getChildFragmentManager();
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(result, this.mChildFragmentManager.getLayoutInflaterFactory());
        return result;
    }
}
```

The **mHost** is a FragmentActivity that contains this fragment. Hence, LayoutInflater that's passed into fragment's onCreateView() contains a reference to the FragmentActivity as a context. So the views effectively observe Activity lifecycle.

How do I make my custom views observe lifecycle events of their containing fragment?

Comment: You can pass fragment lifecycle in the constructor to your View or via setter. `new MyView(getLifecycle())` where `getLifecycle()` is a fragment lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Alexey. Yes, this will work, but will require me to manually instantiate views, and I won't be able to use layoutInflater for XML layouts. I was hoping there's a more elegant way, like wrap up activity into a context wrapper in the fragment, and override some kind of method to pass this wrapper?

Comment: I think that you can try to do this in you init block `(context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("your tag").getLifecycle()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using `onPause()` and `onResume()`, overriding `onDetachedFromWindow()` and `onAttachedToWindow()` in your View class should be enough:

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    //onResume code
}

override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    //onPause code
}
```

You could also make your own lifecycle methods:

```
fun onResume() {}
fun onPause() {}
```

From your Fragment, you can retain a global reference to your View:

```
//`by lazy` only initializes the variable when it's fist called, 
//and then that instance is used for subsequent calls. 
//Make sure you only reference `myView` after `onCreateView()` returns
private val myView by lazy { view.findViewById<MyView>(R.id.my_view) }
```

And then from your Fragment's `onPause()` and `onResume()`, call your View's corresponding methods:

```
override fun onPause() {
    myView.onPause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    myView.onResume()
}
```

EDIT:

For expandability, make your own min-SDK. Create a base Fragment class:

```
open class LifecycleFragment : Fragment() {
    internal fun dispatchOnResume(parent: View) {
        if (parent is CustomLifecycleObserver) parent.onResume()
        if (parent is ViewGroup) {
            for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
                dispatchOnResume(parent.getChildAt(i))
            }
        }
    }

    internal fun dispatchOnPause(parent: View) {
        if (parent is CustomLifecycleObserver) parent.onPause()
        if (parent is ViewGroup) {
            for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
                dispatchOnResume(parent.getChildAt(i))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        dispatchOnResume(view)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        dispatchOnPause(view)
    }
}
```

(`CustomLifecycleListener` would be an interface for your Views to implement, containing `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods.)

Then just extend that class in your other Fragments:

```
class SomeFragment : LifecycleFragment() {}
```

Comment: Hey. Yes, I know I can use onAttached/onDetached to monitor view's visibility state, I am actually currently overriding onWindowVisibilityChanged() in the view, as it gives me exactly the behavior I need. But that seems like a hack when there's a dedicated lifecycle mechanism, and I'd rather use that. Only it's observing the wrong lifecycle :(

Comment: So use the second method.

Comment: Then I lose all the flexibility of using Lifecycle classes alltogether. And I'd need to remember that I have this manual step for every time I change the fragment layout, which happens every couple months. Don't get me wrong, I know that there's many options here. I could have all my views implement a MyLifecycle interface and loop through the whole view hierarcy in the fragment's onPause/onResume, checking if a child is an instance of MyLifecycle and call onPause/onResume on them. But I'd rather avoid all that legwork if there is a way with Lifecycle.

Comment: Change your Fragment's layout? Huh? Just keep the `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods implemented. You could even just do `view.my_view.onResume()` and `view.my_view.onPause()` if you don't want the global reference. Or you could make a base Fragment class that does it for you.

Comment: By "Change the fragment layout" I mean I'll be adding a new custom views that need to be notified of lifecycle. Today it's MyView, one call from onPause, one call from onResume. Tomorrow I'll add MyImageViewPager. Some time later, MyDescriptionView. Now I have 3 calls to 3 views from onPause, and 3 calls from onResume. Some time later I get a requirement to also add MyView to another Fragment, and now I have 2 fragments that override onPause and onResume and iterate over a list of views, calling onPause and onResume. This does work, I just with there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Make a base class, then, with the recursion strategy you were talking about. I can edit in a method to dispatch lifecycle changes recursively.

Comment: Don't sweat it, I can write a recursive function. Thanks!